# Tag Discussion: coco or color-computer

Tags: discussion, tags

Which tag should we use on the main site for the Tandy/Radio Shack Color Computer?

Answer (score 11):

Let's use [color-computer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-computer) because it is what it seems exactly what it is and [coco](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coco) just sounds like this is a tag for cuckoo questions. Basically, keep [color-computer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-computer) and remove [coco](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coco).

Comment: It also preserves "coco" for when we get the first question about Coco Chanel. It could happen.

Comment: You serious @jdv

Comment: I'm always serious about Chanel and TRS-80 products, just never at the same time.

Answer (score 7):

Let's prefer [color-computer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-computer), completely rejecting coco for a tag.

Comment: This tag will almost certainly migrate to others like color-computer-1, color-computer-2, color-computer-3. This fits with apple-ii and the like, so no problem. (This being said, if anyone comes here with a question about the TRS-80 MC-10, I think we should be ok with "mc-10" if only because it was sold under this marque.)

Answer (score -1):

I might be late here, but I'd strongly vote for [coco](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coco), as this is a term for a specific machine, while [color-computer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-computer) is a descriptive phrase used for many computers. Mind you, the C64 was advertized as *'64K Color Computer'.*